# Force javaws to use Java 6 on Mac OS X 10.7

Tags: java, macos, java-web-start, jnlp

I'm running on OS X 10.7.5 and I've got both Java 6 and Java 7 installed.
I've got a bash shell setup to run Java 6 but when I launch a JNLP file
I see the Java 7 splash screen and in the Java console I see

```
Java Web Start 10.25.2.15
Using JRE version 1.7.0_25-b15 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
```

This happens even if I use the full path to javaws

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/javaws foo.jnlp
```

Just to verify this shows the shell is using Java 6:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home
$ type -all javaws
javaws is /usr/bin/javaws
$ ls -l /usr/bin/javaws
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 76 Nov 20 10:13 /usr/bin/javaws -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/javaws*
$ type -all java
java is /usr/bin/java
$ ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 74 Nov 20 10:13 /usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java*
$ java -fullversion
java full version "1.6.0_65-b14-462"
```

Answer (score 5):

This works for me on Mac OS X 10.9, Java version 1.6.0_65:

```
$ /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home/bin/javaws foo.jnlp
```

As discussed in [*JDK 7 Installation for Mac OS X*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html), you can use `java_home` to avoid "hardcoding the full path to the Java command-line tool."

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6 --exec javaws foo.jnlp
```

Comment: The full path you gave works. Setting JAVA_HOME works as long as you also set PATH so that JAVA_HOME/bin is before any other Java.

Comment: My confusion is is part because
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK links to 1.6.0
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current links to A.
And I have no idea what A is. I was assuming it was 1.6.0 since everything
else in that dir is 1.6.0 (1.7 is installed somewhere completely different)
and since CurrentJDK is definitely 1.6.0. Great naming scheme, Apple.
And /usr/bin/java* links to Current, not CurrentJDK.

Comment: And one other weird thing, if I check the
"Allow all applications from ... with this signature"
checkbox it crashes the JVM with 1.6. So I guess I won't do that :)

Comment: The multitude of soft links can be confusing; look in `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/` to see how it's wired.

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that javaws is using JRE, not JDK.
So please uninstall exist JRE, I think it was installed during you first ran JNLP, then download [JRE 1.6 from Oracle web site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html) and run JNLP file again.

Of course, I cannot test it, just a deduction, hope to help you.

Comment: Oracle does not have a Java 1.6 for Mac OS X, only 1.7. The Java 6 version comes from Apple. And I need to have both 1.6 and 1.7 installed and be able to switch back and forth.